# How can i pass and update in real time from a new form the pictureBox1 in form1?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I added a new form to my project the new form contain in the designer webBrowser control. What i'm doing is parsing from html some links then navigate to each link then taking a screenshot and save to the hard disk each image i navigated to in the webBrowser.

In the end when all the links navigated and i have the images on the hard disk i display them on Form1 pictureBox with a hScrollBar.
But now instead waiting for it to finish in the new form and then to show all the images i want to show each saved image on the hard disk in the pictureBox in form1.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.IO;

namespace WebBrowserScreenshots.cs
{
    public partial class WebBrowserScreenshots : Form
    {

        private class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
        {
            [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
            private static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string x, string y);
            public int Compare(string x, string y)
            {
                return StrCmpLogicalW(x, y);
            }
        }

        List<string> newHtmls = new List<string>();
        string uri = "";
        public bool htmlloaded = false;
        int countlinks = 0;
        public int numberoflinks = 0;
        public int numberofimages = 0;
        public List<string> imageList = new List<string>();

        public WebBrowserScreenshots()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            webBrowser1.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
            webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            NavigateToSites();
        }

        string test;
        List<string> htmls;
        private void GetLinks()
        {
            htmlloaded = true;
            for (int i = 1; i < 304; i++)
            {
                if (newHtmls.Count == 1)
                    break;
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load("http://test/page" + i);
                htmls = new List<string>();
                foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
                {
                    string hrefValue = link.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);
                    if (hrefValue.Contains("http") && hrefValue.Contains("attachment"))
                        htmls.Add(hrefValue);
                }
                if (htmls.Count > 0 && abovezero == false)
                RealTimeHtmlList();
            }
        }

        bool abovezero = false;
        private void RealTimeHtmlList()
        {
            abovezero = true;
            for (int x = 0; x < htmls.Count; x++)
            {
                test = htmls[x];
                int index = test.IndexOf("amp");
                string test1 = test.Substring(39, index - 25);
                test = test.Remove(39, index - 35);
                int index1 = test.IndexOf("amp");
                if (index1 > 0)
                    test = test.Remove(index1, 4);
                if (!newHtmls.Contains(test))
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (htmlloaded == true)
                        {
                            newHtmls.Add(test);
                            RealTimeNavigate(test);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void RealTimeNavigate(string tests)
        {

                    uri = test;
                    webBrowser1.Navigate(test);
                    htmlloaded = false;


        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            GetLinks();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            numberoflinks = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            numberofimages = newHtmls.Count;
            htmlloaded = true;
        }

        private void NavigateToLinks()
        {
            if (countlinks != newHtmls.Count)
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (htmlloaded == true)
                    {
                        uri = newHtmls[countlinks];
                        webBrowser1.Navigate(newHtmls[countlinks]);
                        countlinks++;
                        htmlloaded = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        int imagescount = 0;
        public FileInfo[] filesinfo;
        public bool savedall = false;
        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Url.ToString() == uri)
            {

                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(SaveImageFromWebBrowser(webBrowser1));
                bmp = ImageTrim.ImagesTrim(bmp);
                bmp.Save(@"e:\webbrowserimages\Image" + imagescount.ToString() + ".bmp",
                              System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                bmp.Dispose();
                imagescount++;
                htmlloaded = true;
                RealTimeHtmlList();
            }
        }


        private void NavigateToSites()
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, uint nFlags);

        private Bitmap SaveImageFromWebBrowser(Control ctl)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ctl.ClientRectangle.Width, ctl.ClientRectangle.Height);
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                IntPtr hDC = graphics.GetHdc();
                try { PrintWindow(ctl.Handle, hDC, (uint)0); }
                finally { graphics.ReleaseHdc(hDC); }
            }
            return bmp;
        }


    }
}
```

And in form1 i did:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WebBrowserScreenshots.cs
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
        {
            [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
            private static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string x, string y);
            public int Compare(string x, string y)
            {
                return StrCmpLogicalW(x, y);
            }
        }


        public List<string> imageList = new List<string>();
        List<string> numbers = new List<string>();
        WebBrowserScreenshots wbss;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.imageList = Directory.GetFiles(@"e:\webbrowserimages\", "*.bmp").ToList();
            this.imageList.Sort(new MyComparer());

            if (this.imageList.Count > 0)
            {
                hScrollBar1.Minimum = 0;
                hScrollBar1.Value = 0;
                hScrollBar1.Maximum = this.imageList.Count - 1;
                hScrollBar1.SmallChange = 1;
                hScrollBar1.LargeChange = 1;
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(this.imageList[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                timer1.Start();
                wbss = new WebBrowserScreenshots();
                wbss.Show();
            }

        }

        FileInfo[] myFile;
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (wbss.savedall == true)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                hScrollBar1.Enabled = true;
                hScrollBar1.Minimum = 0;
                hScrollBar1.Value = 0;
                hScrollBar1.Maximum = wbss.imageList.Count - 1;
                hScrollBar1.SmallChange = 1;
                hScrollBar1.LargeChange = 1;
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(wbss.imageList[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                if (wbss.htmlloaded == true)
                {
                    var directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"e:\webbrowserimages\");
                    myFile = directory.GetFiles("*.bmp");
                    if (myFile.Length > 0)
                    {
                        var myFiles = (from f in directory.GetFiles("*.bmp")
                                       orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
                                       select f).First();
                        hScrollBar1.Enabled = true;
                        hScrollBar1.Minimum = 0;
                        hScrollBar1.Value = 0;
                        hScrollBar1.Maximum = 1;
                        hScrollBar1.SmallChange = 1;
                        hScrollBar1.LargeChange = 1;
                        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(myFiles.Name);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        private void hScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = (int)hScrollBar1.Value;
            if (pictureBox1.Image != null) pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
            if (this.imageList.Count > 0)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(this.imageList[index]);
                label1.Text = "Displaying image " + index + " of " + (this.imageList.Count - 1);
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(wbss.imageList[index]);
                label1.Text = "Displaying image " + index + " of " + (wbss.imageList.Count - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In form1 i have two options situations could be done.
Once if i'm using in the new form the way that i'm waiting for the backgroundworker to complete and then to wait untill it will navigate to all links in the List newHtmls and then after all images saved on hard disk for example 2453 images then i browse them in form1 pictureBox and hScrollBar.

Or the second option i'm using now that once an image saved to the hard disk in the new form then i will show the image in the form1 pictureBox1.
Then another image saved so now there are two images on hard disk so now show the last saved image. And so on once image saved display it on form1 pictureBox.

Just to show it. So i will see every X seconds images changing in form1 pictureBox.

The problem i'm facing now is in Form1 in this part:

```
if (wbss.htmlloaded == true)
                {
                    var directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"e:\webbrowserimages\");
                    myFile = directory.GetFiles("*.bmp");
                    if (myFile.Length > 0)
                    {
                        var myFiles = (from f in directory.GetFiles("*.bmp")
                                       orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
                                       select f).First();
                        hScrollBar1.Enabled = true;
                        hScrollBar1.Minimum = 0;
                        hScrollBar1.Value = 0;
                        hScrollBar1.Maximum = 1;
                        hScrollBar1.SmallChange = 1;
                        hScrollBar1.LargeChange = 1;
                        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(myFiles.Name);
                    }
                }
```

On the line:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(myFiles.Name);
```

FileNotFoundException: Image3.bmp

But on my hard disk i see Image3.bmp

I will try to narrow cut some code but it's all connected the new form with form1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `myFiles.FullName`. `myFiles.Name` only has the path relative to the directory the file is in, which is not enough to find the file. `FullName` includes the directory, so it's the full absolute path to the file.

And for gasake, name your controls. `Form1` isn't a good name. `pictureBox1` isn't a good name. Even the variable names are misleading - `myFile` for a collection of files, and then `myFiles` for a single file? And why are you calling `GetFiles` again when you already have a list in `myFile`? And why even check for file length? Why not just do `directory.GetFiles("*.bmp").OrderByDescending(i => i.LastWriteTime).Select(i => i.FullName).FirstOrDefault()`?